# Making sure I got the idea . - Ruby on rails login system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently reading a book, and learning ruby on rails. (Agile Web Development with Rails 4th Edition) .In the book it says how to write a simple product list and display it. I am modifying this idea, to create a user login system.
I am only working on the views now.

So I just need to make sure that my idea is right. My idea is:

The show.html file from the USER model, show data for one user. (given of course its ID)
for example : `http://localhost:3000/users/980190974` will give me the html page for the current user right? Now I can allow the user to edit his/her information by using the 
`<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user) %>` link or restrict him from viewing other users by removing the `<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>` << that lists all the users from the database. But before the user views his/her details he must login, using his email and password. So by making an html page, that takes 2 strings (username, and password) searches my mySQL database and return the user ID , that I then use to "render" the user's HTML page.

Is my way of thinking correct? Or am I just completely irrelevant on how Ruby on Rails works? O_o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are heading in the right direction. One thing to point out is that simply removing the link `<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>` is not sufficient to avoid other users from accessing the `/users` path. In the (user) controller you have to use something like:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
    unless current_user.is_admin
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
      return
    end
    ... rest of code here
  end
end
```

where current_user could be a method returning the user object

Comment: If you're looking for a closer example to follow, Ryan Bates did a great screencast on *Authentication from Scratch*: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch